# yii change page without background slideshow refresh

Tags: background, yii, refresh, slideshow, reload

I have a website which uses backgroundstretch to display a slideshow on the background of the website. I use a normal Yii website structure where the content is displayed by: , according to the url.

Now because of the reload the slideshow starts all over again when I go to another page. Is there a way to display the new pages without having to reload the background?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible to load pages using ajax and replace the existing content on top of your rotating slide show, but it would likely be a big architectural change to your website.

Instead you might try storing the current slideshow index in a cookie, and when you load your next page, start the slideshow on the current image instead of the first image.

Comment: Can also be stored in session.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The slideshow now is temporary and after that there is going to be a video background. So I think it's wise to change the structure now. I'll check out ajax...